# Has anyone gotten the LinkedIn Ruby Gem to work at all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rubygems, linkedin-api

The ruby gem for LinkedIn that I'm using is here: http://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin

When calling LinkedIn::Client.new with a valid API Key and Secret, I get this:

undefined method `tap' for #

Other people have had the same problem, see http://developer.linkedin.com/message/2363

Don't think anyone has proposed a solution yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was answered over here on the LinkedIn forums: http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/1170

FYI: Seems like the answer is to upgrade Rails to 2.3.x

Answer (score 0):

That would seem to be a Ruby 1.9 feature, so if you're not using Ruby 1.9, it's not going to be there.